# Debugging Connection.prepareStatement method

Tags: java, jdbc, weblogic, prepared-statement, breakpoints

At work we are using the **Connection.prepareStatement** method in many places in the code and I'm trying to catch when this method is called when I'm performing some flow in our application.
For example, I'm performing flow A and I want to see what queries are getting prepared with the **prepareStatement** method and then executed.
I prefer not to put a breakpoint in every place in code that calls to this method (there are more then hundred places).
The class that implements **Connection.prepareStatement** is **sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcConnection** and I tried in the Outline window to put a breakpoint there on **prepareStatement** method but it didn't stop in the breakpoint.

Does someone have a good solution for this?

thanks.

p.s: 
I don't know if it matters but the application runs on weblogic server.

Comment: I just tried what you described and it worked fine for me in Eclipse ([screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eIbO2.png)).

Comment: it is not working for me. After pressing F5 when getting to **connection.prepareStatement(QUERY);** , I'm getting  to **JdbcConnector$ConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(String) line: 6381**. With eclipse decompiler plugin I can see the class and it doesn't have the 6381 line at all.

Comment: Yes, you may be unable to step into the JDBC-ODBC Bridge code itself, at least not without the actual source code for it. Do you really need to do that? You certainly can "see what queries are getting prepared with the prepareStatement method" because you can see the SQL statement that gets passed to the `prepareStatement` method. (What the JDBC-ODBC Bridge code does from then on might be somewhat interesting, but it is not likely something you want to mess with.)

Comment: yes, but I had more than handred places in the code that calls to **prepareStatement** method and I want to put only one breakpoint.